# uTOLED-20-G2 display compatibility

Tags: display, compatibility

This might be a touch specific, but does anyone know if the [4D Systems uTOLED-20-G2](http://www.4dsystems.com.au/product/1/5/4D_Intelligent_Display_Modules/uTOLED_20_G2/) can be used as a display?  They make an [adapter](http://www.4dsystems.com.au/product/5/40/Raspberry_Pi_Display_Modules/4D_Serial_Pi_Adaptor/) but I cannot locate any info and the documentation for the adapter was written November of last year, but the display was released earlier this year I believe.

If anyone has any info about it or where I can look, because I've search but most of the stuff I find is just product info or websites selling both an RPi or the display, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> This environment is also provided to transform the display module into
>   a slave serial display module, allowing the user to control the
>   display from any host microcontroller or device with a serial port

So you should be able to connect it to the GPIO pins and send data to it. But you can't connect like a normal display. So you can't get the video card's output onto it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the datasheet of the adapter (http://www.4dsystems.com.au/product/5/40/Raspberry_Pi_Display_Modules/4D_Serial_Pi_Adaptor/ Rev 1.1):

> The 4D Raspberry Pi Serial Adaptor is compatible with the following 4D
>   Systems display modules:
>
> - uLCD-24PT
> - uLCD-28PT
> - uLCD-32PT
> - uOLED-96-G1/G2
> - uOLED-128-G1/G2
> - uOLED-160-G1/G2
> - uLCD-144-G1/G2
> - uLCD-43 (All versions)
> - uLCD-24-PTU
> - uLCD-28-PTU
> - uLCD-32-PTU
> - uLCD-32W-PTU

Since the uTOLED display is not listed, I'd be sceptical, whether the display is fully supported.